# How to calculate "total" using Javascript and SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to calculte the Sum of the amounts and show it when a value from a dropdown is selected.
this is the query in SQl Server;

```
select Sum(Total) from tbl_CordinatorPayments where fk_repId=2
```

So, This is  my drop down;

```
<select name="selectCity" id="CityDDL" class="form-control" onchange="getValue()">
                <option value="-1">--Select Rep--</option>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.reps)
                {
                    <option value="@item.id">@item.Name</option>
                }

            </select>
```

and im getting the **Id** of the value from dropdown by using this;

```
function getValue() {
    var value = $("#CityDDL").val();
}
```

So, what I want is that when user selects any value from drop down, It should run this Sql Query;

```
"select Sum(Total) from tbl_CordinatorPayments where fk_repId=Id from the drop down"
```

In a LINQ format or Entity framework query format and the total should be displayed in

```
<p id="Total"></p>
```

I dont know how to get the value of Id from dropdown and use it in a where clause of a query.

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to post the value to your controller. I think you don't need to read value using jquery unless you want to send the request using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery, you need to call the mvc or API controller to get the total value like below

```
function getValue() {
    var value = $("#CityDDL").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%: Url.Action("yourActionMethod")%>',
        data: { 'id' : value},
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#Total').text(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#Total').text("Error encountered while getting total");
        }
    });
}
```

In MVC controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult yourActionMethod(int id)
    {          
         var result = _db.tbl_CordinatorPayments.Where(cp => cp.fk_repId == id).Sum(cp => cp.Total);
         return result;
    }
```